# How Cadence clean up tasklist records

Tags: cadence-workflow

Is there a cost for each task list registered (e.g. database record)?

Is it okay if I use a dynamic tasklist? e.g. per instanceID so that tasklist won't affect each other.

Answer (score 0):

Each takslist cost less than 1KB but accumulated it could be a big number.
So clean up is important.

It depends on the backend database of Cadence cluster.

In SQL, regular tasklist will still be deleted if there are no tasks anymore, or all tasks under it are expired.
workflow sticky tasks have only 10s timeout so usually they are easy to delete. Regular tasklist can be never deleted only if there is a task with infinite timeout stays there. Activity task usually have minutes to hours timeout, but regular workflow decision tasks have infinite timeout due to the protocol design(so that workflow worker can be down for a month and can still come back to pick up the workflow task) But if tasks are drained, the tasklists will be deleted.
See Tasklist scanner workflow for SQL: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/master/service/worker/scanner/tasklist/handler.go#L43

Cassandra is sorta worse in this case. It only applies TTL for sticky tasklist and never delete regular ones. The design thought Cassandra can scale out easily so they don’t worry about the space storage for tasklist.

See Cassandra applies TTL to sicky tasklist: https://github.com/uber/cadence/blob/9a46d9d483cfdb8fd5ca77d1f448d79d78b0e791/common/persistence/nosql/nosqlTaskStore.go#L172